# Why constructors and destructor are not called when pointer is created & destroyed?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, destructor

Why constructors and destructor are not called when pointer is created & destroyed ?
I m really confused because pointer is also an object just like normal object..memory is also allocated for pointer..then why constructor and destructor is not called of class

Comment: A pointer is not a instance of the pointed to class. There _is no_ object to call the constructor on. Asking why a pointer doesn't call the constructor is equal to asking why we don't build a house right on top of each street sign.

Comment: You mean like `MyStruct* ptr;` ? It is because pointer is a built-in type. It is "pointing to" `MyStruct`, not "is" `MyStruct`.

Comment: _" because pointer is also an object "_  You are correct about this - a pointer is its own distinct object.  It is not the object that is pointed to.  Destroying either object does not destroy the other object.

Comment: @tkausl there is an object, of pointer type.

Comment: If you have a custom iterator or pointer class that has a constructor and destructor, then those functions will be called.  All other simple pointer types are intrinsic and you won't see constructor or destructor called for them; similar to an `int` type.

Comment: An ordinary raw pointer per se behaves, in this respect, identically to an ordinary `int` – there are no constructors/destructors for `int`s, there are none for pointers. All you can do with is assigning a value to, just as with `int`s. In the pointer case, it's the address of an object, which might be created by `new`, but you can as well let it point to an object with local storage duration or a global one.

Comment: Where is [mcve]? With current description it is impossible to tell what you have done wrong or what you misunderstood.

Comment: Important, too: If pointers *did* implicitly delete the objects they point to you would run into big trouble if the pointed objects are local or global ones (not created with `new`) or if two (or more) pointers pointed to the same object – leading to double (multiple) deletion!

Comment: @MarekR seemed clear enough to me: "I write a constructor. I create a pointer. Constructor is not called. Why?"

Comment: @user253751 note there are also a smart pointers.

Comment: The constructor of a pointer is a trivial no-op.  The destructor of a pointer is also a trivial no-op.  They are called, but they don't do anything, and the optimizer can eliminate their do-nothing-ness.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `SomeClass` calls the constructor of `SomeClass` if it has one. Creating an `int` calls the constructor of `int` if it has one. Creating a `SomeClass *` calls the constructor of `SomeClass *` if it has one.

You can write a constructor for `SomeClass` and then it will call it. `int` doesn't have a constructor so it doesn't call one. `SomeClass *` doesn't have a constructor so it doesn't call one.

`SomeClass *` isn't the same as `SomeClass`

Same for destructors.

(this explanation is simplified a bit)

Comment: Errm... First sentence: *'calls the constructor of'*, second sentence '*doesn't have one'*...

Comment: *" Creating an int calls the constructor of int..."* Built in types don't have constructors.

Comment: @JasonLiam hence "this explanation is simplified". Know the target audience.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, you can probably change that to say: *"this explanation is simplified **as built in types don't have constructors**"*. Note the added bold part.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do in the construction of pointer objects, in much the same way as there is nothing to do in the construction of `int` objects, or of objects of a class that has a trivial constructor.

You can think of it like the (lack of) constructor for

```
class Trivial {
    int member;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why constructors and destructor are not called when pointer is created & destroyed?

Because a pointer is not an object of type `SomeClass` but instead an object of type `SomeClass*`. In other words, when we create a pointer to some class-type say `SomeClass` then we're not creating an object of type `SomeClass` but of `SomeClass*`.

Constructor are called when an object of type `SomeClass` is created.

Basically,

```
//type SomeClass* is not the same as the type SomeClass
SomeClass* != SomeClass
```